# AAPT2 failing to merge resources on Docker

Tags: android, docker, aapt, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build an Android application inside a docker container on a CI server and aapt2 is failing to merge the resources.

Base Docker Image is `openjdk:8-alpine`

The packages being installed in my image from alpine repositories are:

```
build-base alpine-sdk bash ca-certificates curl gcc git gzip musl-dev openssh-client python python-dev tar unzip wget
```

Also I'm downloading and installing Glibc from

```
https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.25-r0/glibc-2.25-r0.apk
```

The installed android sdk packages are

```
build-tools;26.0.0-rc2 platforms;android-25 platform-tools extras;android;m2repository extras;google;m2repository extras;google;google_play_services
```

The application is currently using `Gradle Wrapper 4.0-rc-1`

The error is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:303)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:235)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:224)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:121)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:96)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:611)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:566)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:201)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:168)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:303)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:177)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: Error: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.postWriteAction(MergedResourceWriter.java:596)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:45)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:237)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:301)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:412)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:194)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.postWriteAction(MergedResourceWriter.java:564)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.AaptV2Jni.lambda$compile$0(AaptV2Jni.java:90)
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: Failed to load shared library '/tmp/aapt2_8990614974494423638.dir/libc++.so'
    at com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Jni.loadLibraryFromResource(Aapt2Jni.java:162)
    at com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Jni.loadSharedLibrariesFromResources(Aapt2Jni.java:204)
    at com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Jni.load(Aapt2Jni.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Jni.<clinit>(Aapt2Jni.java:43)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/aapt2_8990614974494423638.dir/libc++.so: Error relocating /tmp/aapt2_8990614974494423638.dir/libc++.so: strtoll_l: symbol not found
    at com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Jni.loadLibraryFromResource(Aapt2Jni.java:159)
    ... 4 more


BUILD FAILED in 30s
```

I tried installing different alpine packages with no luck.
I have the feeling that this is related to Glibc and/or Musl libraries, but I don't understand it enough not to know how to solve this problem

Also, everything works fine on a very similar image (alpine based too) with build-tools 25.0.3 and Gradle 3.5.

Any clues? Thanks

Comment: Ended up switching to openjdk:8-jdk which is based on debian and not a lot bigger to be honest. This is however a temporary solution.

Answer (score 2):

I stumble upon the same error. The problem as you suspected is that Alpine Linux ships with Musl instead of GNU libc, the Android SDK tooling requires glibc.

You could use something like this: https://github.com/frol/docker-alpine-glibc, or create a similar image on your own if you're comfortable with someone else compiling glibc for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which libraries are missing (ENOENT singal) with: `$ strace ./aapt2`
Then try to create a simbolic link of those libraries to the expected path.

Answer (score 0):

Alpine Linux ships with Musl instead of GNU libc, the Android SDK tooling requires glibc.

Adding "The GNU C Library compatibility layer for musl" did the trick for me.

```
apk add gcompat
```